# It doesn't go anywhere but it leaves every day

Tags: riddle

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

I'm always in the same place

Yet I never stand still

What am I?

Hint

> Every time you look at me I wave

Comment: Just a note, but if your riddle has a "Not it" section, you should probably rewrite it so it offers only unique solution.

Comment: Honestly I'm surprised I've need one. Most people I ask in person get it on the first or second try, but I live in cali.

Comment: It doesn't work like that in all countries and all schedules differ daily. 
The first line just doesn't work. In my case, today, it comes in the morning, leaves around noon, comes back in the afternoon and leaves again in the evening. Which explains why your locals have the same perspective of this thing as you have, and others around the world do not.

Comment: @PL457 To be absolutely honestly correct, it's night high tide. That would be the tide that would come in the evening and leave in the day, however most people don't actually know that there are two tides daily

Comment: @PL457 everywhere has a day tide and a night tide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not strictly true, but are you

> The tide?

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

> You come and go again in between too

I'm always in the same place

> The sea is always in the same place

Yet I never stand still

> The sea constantly moves

Comment: You mentioned the answer in this.

Comment: @RobertMennell Is it any good now?

Comment: It goes out in the morning and returns in the evening,  I an the tide. Always found at the beach and I always move (waves)

Answer (score 9):

Is it

> shoes

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

> Every Morning you wear it out and evening you come back with them.

I'm always in the same place

> They are always on your feet.

Yet I never stand still

> you would be walking with shoes.

Comment: No. I'm always in the same place.

Answer (score 8):

Are you...

> The letter 'E'?

It doesn't go anywhere but it leaves every day

> Not in "go", always in "leaves"

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

> Not in "morning", always in "evening"

I'm always in the same place

> Always in "the", "same", "place"

Yet I never stand still

> Not in "stand", "still"

Comment: Interesting take. But no, I'm not a letter.

Comment: @RobertMennell Eh, I figured it was weak, but worth a shot.

Comment: Always question

Comment: I like this answer very much

Answer (score 7):

Are you

> The moon?

Every morning I leave, every evening I return.

> Self-explanatory

I'm always in the same place.

> We always see the same side of the moon, and the moon is always in the sky.

Yet I never stand still.

> It rotates around the earth (and much more movement).

Comment: I also had that thought.. but yes moon is kind of related to light. PS:It would be better if you use spoilers . :)

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> The hour hand of the clock

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

> We see the hand when we get up. This could be takes as leaving. E.g. at 6 AM. In the evening it return to the same number (6 PM)

I'm always in the same place

> Always found on the dial.

Yet I never stand still

> Hour hand always moves a little.

What am I?

> The hour hand of a clock.

Comment: Nope. Interesting take though.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Umbrella

1.

> In the morning person takes it with him and returns with it in the evening

2.

> it is always in the same place. Usually the hands or a bag pack

3.

> It is always goes with the person kind of not still

Comment: I had originally though darkness, but Night fits better. +1

Comment: No. Interesting interpretation though

Comment: As @ChronoD suggested could it be darkness

Comment: No. Nothing related to light.

Comment: @RobertMennell updates made

Comment: Nope. It moves away from its original area

Answer (score 2):

the answer is

> glasses

Every morning I leave, every evening I return

> glasses leave with the owner and return with the owner

I'm always in the same place

> glasses are always on the forehead

Yet I never stand still

> glasses always move when the owner moves

What am I?

> you are glasses or specks

Comment: You wear them on your forehead? Not getting much use up there I'm sure.

Comment: oh ! i get sorry bad English. i meant that glasses are always on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> sleep ?

It doesn't go anywhere but it leaves every day.
I'm always in the same place.

> brain is responsible for sleep(hypothalamus I think).

Yet I never stand still.

> Normally we don't sleep while standing !.

Comment: Nope. Not a bodily function

Answer (score -2):

> You are a river/stream. Constantly running and moving but never getting any closer to what u truly desire.